# Variance of the minimum between a constant and a random variable

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be a random variable, and $c$ a constant.

How can we prove that:

$var[min(X,c)]\le var[X]$?

Comment: This is equivalent to showing $var[\max(Y,0)]\le var[Y]$ by letting $Y=c-X$.  You then have $\max(Y,0)$ non-negative if it helps

Comment: To add to @Henry's comment, it helps to remember that the variance of a constant is zero.

Comment: ?? I don't get it: are these comments supposed to be *hints*? Because these are in fact at most tangential remarks...

Comment: It becomes transparent if you observe that the variance is $\inf_{t} E((X-t)^2)$. Given a  $1$-Lipschitz function $\phi$, compare $\phi\circ X - \phi(t)$  and $X-t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two trivial cases: if $Pr(X \le c)=1$ then you have equality, while if $Pr(X \ge c)=1$ you have $)$ less than or equal to a non-negative variance.  Otherwise $c$ is within the interval that supports $X$.

I am going to let $Y=c-X$ and then prove the equivalent statement $var[\max(Y,0)]\le var[Y]$.  It is not necessary, but it makes what is non-negative or negative more obvious and reduces the the number of terms.  Let:

- $p_1=\Pr(Y \ge 0)$, which is non-negative
- $p_2=\Pr(Y \lt 0)$, which is non-negative and $p_2=1-p_1$
- $\mu_1 = E[Y | Y \ge 0]$, which is non-negative
- $\mu_2 = E[Y | Y \lt 0]$, which is non-positive
- $s_1^2 = E[Y^2 | Y \ge 0]$, which is non-negative and $s_1^2 \ge \mu_1^2$ from the conditional variance
- $s_1^2 = E[Y^2 | Y \lt 0]$, which is non-negative and $s_2^2 \ge \mu_2^2$ from the conditional variance
- $Z=\max(Y,0)$, which is non-negative

Then:

- $E[Y]=p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2$
- $E[Z]=p_1\mu_1$
- $E[Y^2]=p_1 s_1^2+p_2 s_2^2$
- $E[Z^2]=p_1 s_1^2$
- $var[Y]=p_1 s_1^2+p_2 s_2^2 - p_1^2\mu_1^2-2p_1 p_2\mu_1\mu_2-p_2^2\mu_2^2$
- $var[Z]=p_1 s_1^2- p_1^2\mu_1^2$
- $var[Y]-var[Z] = p_2 s_2^2 -2p_1 p_2\mu_1\mu_2-p_2^2\mu_2^2 = p_2(s_2^2-\mu_2^2)-2p_1 p_2\mu_1\mu_2 + p_1 p_2\mu_2^2$

and we know that $p_2(s_2^2-\mu_2^2)\ge 0$, that $-2p_1 p_2\mu_1\mu_2 \ge 0$, and that $p_1 p_2\mu_2^2 \ge 0$,

so $var[Y]-var[Z] \ge 0$, i.e. $var[\max(Y,0)]\le var[Y]$ and thus $var[\min(X,c)]\le var[X]$.